# convention of a default atlas

Tags: differential-geometry, convention

Recently, I have been studying the basics of differential geometry and te necessary preliminaries. I arrived at the construction of differential structure on topological manifolds, where the non-uniqueness of these structures is mentioned. After this, the precence of a (pick of) structure seems to be assumed in most of what follows.

From what I can tell, it often looks like there is an obvious choice, while the others are labled 'exotic'. This seems to be most obvious when looking at $\mathbb{R^4}$. There is an entire wikipedia page dedicated to exotic versions of $\mathbb{R^4}$, that are homeomorphic, but not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R^4}$ as a smooth manifold. My question then becomes: when no differential structure is given, is there a convention of a structure to pick? How do I distinguish between the exotic structures and the 'usual' ones. In the case of $\mathbb{R^4}$, I would bet the default structure would/could consist of an atlas, build from all of the open sets, equipped with the identity from $\mathbb{R^4}$ into $\mathbb{R^4}$.

As my background is in physics, I am in particular interested in the differential structure that one would usually establish on a manifold in the context of four dimentional General Relativity. But perhaps this should be a sepparate question on the physics SE. I apologize in advance for improper use of jargon or other, possibly trivial mistakes. Feel free to correct me.

*edit*
To further clairify the source of this question as well as my confusion:
From my experience with GR it seems physicists usually take a (pseudo?) Riemanian metric as a starting point. To me it seems this fixes only a piece of the manifold, described by the single coordinate map. The physicist would then declare that this describes a manifold, but i am uncertain how to pick the additional contributions to the atlas. On top of this, the physicist might sometimes perform a coordinate transformation, which seems tricky to me when the rest of the chart was not well comunicated. How would I know if the new coordinates would be in the same chart? In addition, I am uncertain weither this should be discussed here, or on the physiscs SE.

*edit 2*
I will ay some point pose a related question about GR on the physics SE. The question then reduces to one of mathematical convention: weither or not $\mathbb{R}^n$ is usually assumed to be equipped with the identity on open sets, as an atlas, and weither or not other 'assumptions' exist when the atlas definition is left out.

*edit 3*
new related thread in physics SE https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/566643/how-to-select-which-differentiable-manifold-to-use-to-model-spacetime/661820

Comment: My impression was always that spacetime was $\mathbb R^4$ with the usual differentiable structure but some weird pseudo-Riemannian metric. So the topological and differentiable structures are the usual ones (and certainly that's the one you should assume unless someone tells you otherwise) but there's an interesting way of measuring distance. My hope is that physicists don't have to worry about exotic spheres.

Comment: ah, ok. it seems i confused properties of the metric with properties of the differentiable structure. I was not aware the metric was completely unrelated to this. I suppose this was caused by sloppy language then. Your comment makes a lot of sence. If you combine your statement with bowditch's answer I am inclined to accept it and close the question.

Comment: As for the exotic structures: if you search for Brans, Carl H. and Asselmeyer-Maluga, Torsten on arxiv, you will see that there are some people who think that the exotic structures might have some physical meaning.

Comment: Well I'm hoping someone who knows what they're talking about will write an answer (and on first glance it seems someone has). I've never used an indefinite metric in my life. It does, by the way, have something to do with the differentiable structure in that we demand that the pseudo-metric vary smoothly along the manifold, so they do interact.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you're right; if $M$ is presented to you as being embedded in $\mathbb R^n$, the default atlas would be some covering of $M$ with open sets in $\mathbb R^m$ (standard topology) and the identity map on $\mathbb R^m$, where $m=\dim(M)$.

Comment: What if it isn't presented as such, is one still supposed to pick the atlas it would inherit from the smallest possible embedding in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: That's dodgy -- do you have a link to where this is done?

Comment: Not really, I feel like I have seen this somewhere, but I am mostly just wondering whether or not this could be expected. I guess not. This then still leaves me wondering what structure one usually picks in d=4 GR

Comment: Also, $\mathbb{R}^4$ was never presented to me as embedded in anything, although I suppose this is trivial

Comment: What do you mean by "embedded in $\mathbb R^n$" and "identity map on $\mathbb R^m$"? I'm just trying to figure out what the starting data is and what's being constructed from that.

Comment: @Bowditch Please note edit 2 of this question. If you can expand your answer to clairify the above comments, I will except this answer.

Comment: @Fictional I'm afraid I don't really know what you need beyond what I've said above. Could you please clarify or give a concrete example of the situation that's confusing you

Comment: @Bowditch I am mostly talking about hoots comment. I suppose n\leq m and that the embedding is a smooth one for example? On top of that, you could add the fact that no default atlas is implied when the manifold is not presented as embedded...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to comment on Hoot's comment, spacetime is (unless you assume there is no gravity, but then you are really doing special relativity and the whole manifold aspect becomes a bit obsolete as you have global coordinates available) definitively not $\mathbb{R}^4$. It is a 4-dimensional connected (and usually taken to be) non-compact smooth manifold which is equipped with a Lorentzian metric, i.e. a Minkowski metric at each tangent space.

To see what physicists do and don't do when discussing GR you have to realise what assumptions we make. We assume, or rather demand (following Einstein), that spacetime is locally a Minkowski space, and that's probably what you have interpreted as [insert source] taking a Lorentzian metric as a starting point locally and then working from there. We also assume that spacetime is an actual manifold, so there is an atlas, we just don't really worry about because we consider stuff locally (although the global structure is eventually certainly relevant).

Comment: But when only considering the local Minkowski space, no gravitational effects can be studied. On top of this, if the global structure is ignored, how could one studie cosmology? Would you know how such an atlas would be constructed? Or perhaps this question belongs on the physics SE?

Comment: I don't think that's true, because the Christoffel symbols and all other non-trivialities are still there. And, I think it does. I had something to say, but do not feel comfortable enough further answering these (good) questions.

Comment: "It is a 4-dimensional connected (and usually taken to be) non-compact smooth manifold which is equipped with a Lorentzian metric, i.e. a Minkowski metric at each tangent space." This does not exclude $\mathbb{R}^4$ (together with some non-trivial metric) as a possibility. $\mathbb{R}^d$ can be made into such a manifold. Also isnt curvature defined in terms of the directional derivative of the metric tensor? If so a non-trivial metric will give.you non-trivial curvature even if the set, topology and atlas are trivial.

Comment: Seesh, thanks for commenting on this after 4 years. Indeed you are right - I cringed reading my answer. I hope I meant that spacetime is not $\mathbb{R}^4$ meaning the regular Riemannian space with standard metric and such. I also think you are right about the curvature.